# How do I use a rails check_box?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller:

```
class PortTestingController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @ports = {"80" => false, "443" => false, "2195" => true, "28009" => false}
    end
end
```

This is what I have in my view:

```
- @ports.each_with_index do |(key,value), index|
      - fields_for "ports[#{index}]", port do |f|
        f.checkbox "#{key}" "#{key}"
      =key
```

I've been looking at the documentation for a check_box:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box

and I have no idea what to put write for my checkbox. What's the method? What options can I pass in? What is checked value and unchecked value?

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a confusing aspect of `ActionView`.

Since you are calling `f.check_box` and not just simply `check_box` (at least you will be once you fix your typo), the function you are actually calling is this one:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-check_box

However, the `FormBuilder` method just passes the object represented by `f` as the first parameter to a `FormHelper`. So you can think of it like `f.check_box ...` is equivalent to `check_box f.object ...`

The `method` is the `ActionView` attribute you want to set.

There are various `options` that can be passed, but I find I generally just pass `{}`

The `checked` value is what you want to pass if the checkbox is checked. By default it will be 1. Similarly, `unchecked` passed by the form if the checkbox is unchecked. Sometimes I find that I want to reverse the polarity of a checkbox and I want to keep track of unchecked boxes, so I set `checked` to 0 and `unchecked` to 1.

Now to a more important point. All of these `ActionView` methods are designed to work with `ActiveRecord` models which you do not currently have. Your controller isn't setting @ports to a value derived from `ActiveRecord::Base`. I think you should read up on that some more.